# how to manipulate web config secret in kube-prometheus stack?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

i have deployed the latest chart[these are all the secrets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uptd8.png)

how to change prometheus-kube-prometheus-stack-1651-prometheus-web-config this secret through the helm chart?

[this is secret without any changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFFUc.png)

Comment: were you able to enable basic auth?